# Problems with tree and arrows

Tags: arrows, forest

I am using LyX and I have to create a tree of a stemma codicum. I used a `forest` package with forest library `linguistics`. The obtained result is good but I still need to create an arrow linking `L` to `\Gamma`. Could anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[oneside,italian,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% Load forest linguistics library, if available
\@ifpackagelater{forest}{2016/02/20}{%
\useforestlibrary*{linguistics}
}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{italian}%
\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, fit=band [[$\varGamma$][V]] [, fit=band[[S][F]][[C][L]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\selectlanguage{english}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! i suspect that you use `forest` package ... to help you we need to see complete code of your tree. the best in form of small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` which will produce image of your tree.

Comment: Thank you! I have just edited the main message. And yes, you are right I meant forest package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary*{linguistics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, fit=band
    [[$\varGamma$, name=a][V]]
    [, fit=band
         [[S][F]]
         [[C][L,name=b]]]
]%]]
\draw[red,->] (a) to [out=300, in=210] (b);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

in your code you have to much `]`.